Best Practices for Integrating Python Scripts with Spring Boot via Jython
We're working on a Full Stack Spring Boot project. One of our team members has developed a Python script for web scraping and audio (speech) integration to interact with the data. This script has been integrated into our Spring Boot application using Jython. However, we have some concerns about the good practices and would appreciate your insights on the following points:
Has anyone successfully used Jython in a production environment to integrate Python scripts with Java? What were the key challenges and benefits you encountered?
Would creating a separate Python endpoint and interacting through APIs be a better approach compared to using Jython? What are the pros and cons of this method?
Since it is feasible to rebuild the functionality of the Python script directly in Java, why should we use Python for this task? What are the potential challenges and benefits of implementing this functionality directly in Java?
We appreciate any experiences or advice you can share!
Thank you!

"best practices" questions like this almost always get closed as opinion-based. SO questions are expected to have objectively correct answers that can be accepted.

Jython is an extremely versatile language. If you want many real world, production environment examples, search the forums for Inductive Automation. Their Ignition platform makes extensive use of Jython.

I was going to say look at the releases and see that not much is happening in the jython universe, but there was a 2.7.4 release last month. Two years after the release of 2.7.3. I don't think using jython for a long term project is the best plan. Are you going to be able to find someone to solve complex bugs or implement non-trivial features in two years time? In ten? I have used jython and IronPython when required, but would advise my past self to push for a defined API.
